# Need help fixing my implementation of RK4

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I'd appreciate it if someone more experienced on implementation would help me to spot my logical flaw in my current code. For the past couple of hours I've been stuck with the implementation and testing of various step sizes for the following RK4 function to solve the [Lotka-Volterra Differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation).

I did my absolute best to ensure readability of the code and comment out crucial steps, so the code below should be clear.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def model(state,t):
    """
    A function that creates an 1x2-array containing the Lotka Volterra Differential equation

    Parameter assignement/convention:
    a   natural growth rate of the preys
    b   chance of being eaten by a predator
    c   dying rate of the predators per week
    d   chance of catching a prey 
    """

    x,y = state     # will corresponding to initial conditions  
                    # consider it as a vector too 

    a = 0.08
    b = 0.002
    c = 0.2
    d = 0.0004

    return np.array([ x*(a-b*y) , -y*(c - d*x) ]) # corresponds to [dx/dt, dy/dt]


def rk4( f, x0, t):
    """ 
    4th order Runge-Kutta method implementation to solve x' = f(x,t) with x(t[0]) = x0.

    INPUT:
        f     - function of x and t equal to dx/dt. 

        x0    - the initial condition(s).  
                Specifies the value of x @ t = t[0] (initial).  
                Can be a scalar or a vector (NumPy Array)

                Example: [x0, y0] = [500, 20]

        t     - a time vector (array) at which the values of the solution are computed at.
                t[0] is considered as the initial time point 
                the step size h is dependent on the time vector, choosing more points will 
                result in a smaller step size. 


    OUTPUT:
        x     - An array containing the solution evaluated at each point in the t array.

    """

    n = len( t )
    x = np.array( [ x0 ] * n )      # creating an array of length n 

    for i in xrange( n - 1 ):
        h = t[i+1]- t[i]            # step size, dependent on time vector

        # starting below - the implementation of the RK4 algorithm:
        # for further informations visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_methods

        # k1 is the increment based on the slope at the beginning of the interval (same as Euler)
        # k2 is the increment based on the slope at the midpoint of the interval 
        # k3 is AGAIN the increment based on the slope at the midpoint 
        # k4 is the increment based on the slope at the end of the interval

        k1 = f( x[i], t[i] )
        k2 = f( x[i] + 0.5 * h * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h ) 
        k3 = f( x[i] + 0.5 * h * k2, t[i] + 0.5 * h )  
        k4 = f( x[i] + h * k3, t[i] + h  )

        # finally computing the weighted average and storing it in the x-array
        t[i+1] = t[i] + h
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * ( ( k1 + 2.0 * ( k2 + k3 ) + k4 ) / 6.0 )

    return x


################################################################
# just the graphical output

# initial conditions for the system

x0 = 500
y0 = 20


# vector of times
t = np.linspace( 0, 200, 150 )

result = rk4( model,[x0,y0], t )


plt.plot(t,result)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population Size')
plt.legend(('x (prey)','y (predator)'))
plt.title('Lotka-Volterra Model')
plt.show()
```

The current output looks 'okay-ish' on a small interval and then goes 'berserk'. Oddly enough the code seems to perform better when I choose a larger step size rather than a small one, which points out that my implementation must be wrong, or maybe my model is off. I couldn't spot the error myself.

Output (wrong):

[image: current output by the RK4 algorithm]

and this is the desired output which can be easily obtained by using one of Scipys integration modules. Note that on the time interval [0,50] the simulation seems correct, then it gets worse by every step.

[image: correct desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you fell into the same trap I've occasionally fallen into: your initial `x0` array contains integers, and thus, all resulting `x[i]` values will be converted to an integer after calculation.

Why is that? Because `int` is the type of your initial conditions:

```
x0 = 500
y0 = 20
```

The solution is, of course, to explicitly make them `float`s:

```
x0 = 500.
y0 = 20.
```

So why does `scipy` does it correctly when you feed it integer starting values? It probably converts them to `float` before starting the actual calculation. You could for example do:

```
x = np.array( [ x0 ] * n, dtype=np.float)
```

and then you're still safe to use integer initial conditions without problems.
At least this way, the conversion is done inside the function for once and for all, and if you ever use it again half a year (or, someone else uses it), you can't fall into that trap again.

Comment: Thank you so very much, it is a relief to know that my implementation was not for nothing after all. You saved me from another day of headaches.